# Solving recurrence: T(n)=sqrt(2)T(n/2)+log(n)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence, master-theorem

Given the equation `T(n)=sqrt(2)T(n/2)+log(n)`.

The solution points to case 1 of the M.T. with a complexity class of O(sqrt(n)). However after my understanding log(n) is polynomial greater then sqrt(n). Am I missing something?

I used the definition as following: n^e = log_b(a) where a = sqrt(2) and b = 2. This would give me e = 1/2 < 1. log n is obviously polynomial greater then n^e.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. **log<sub>x</sub> n** is not greater than **√n**.

Consider `n=256`,

`√n = 16`,

and

**log<sub>2</sub> 256 = 8** (let us assume base `x=2`, as with many of the computational problems).

In your recurrence,

```
T(n)= √2 T(n/2) + log(n)
a = √2, b = 2 and f(n) = log(n)
```

**log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>2</sub> √2 = 1/2**.

Since **log n < n<sup>a</sup>**, for `a > 0`, We have Case 1 of Master Theorem.

There for `T(n) = Θ(√n)`.

Comment: My bad for only testing a few low numbers instead of actually looking at what happens if we use great n's. Thank you for your detailed answer, it really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using the masters theorem you get: `a=sqrt(2)`, `b = 2` and therefore `c = logb(a) = 1/2`. Your `f(n) = log(n)` and therefore you fall into the first case.

So your complexity is `O(sqrt(n))`